# Enabling External Interrupts in PIC24F (PIC24F32KA302)

Tags: pic, microchip

I am trying to enable pin23 of the PIC as an input to trigger an external interrupt. 
I would like to set pin23 as INT2 to trigger in the rising edge and with the input configured with a pull-down resistor.
This is the code of what I am trying to do:

```
void EnableINT2IE()
{
    PORTBbits.RB12=1;            //RB12, pin23 is an input.
    //CNPD1bits.CN14PDE = 0;     //pull down resistor
    //CNEN1bits.CN14IE=1;        //enable change notification.
    IFS1bits.INT2IF = 0;         //clear interrupt flag.
    INTCON2bits.INT2EP =0;       //Interrupt iNT2E is on the positive edge
    IPC7bits.INT2IP =7;          //set highest interrupt priority to INT2
    IEC1bits.INT2IE=1;           //Enable INT2IE interruption
}
```

I have tried both with and without the two commented lines (the are intended to configure the pull down resistor).
The interrupt vector looks like this. It calls some existing functions and turns on/off a LED.

```
void __attribute__((interrupt,auto_psv)) _INT2Interrupt(void) //External Interrupt 2
{
  PORTBbits.RB3 = 1;  //turn on an led,
  RafraichirPTH();    
  RafraichirE();
  LogAppend();
  SfopAppend();
  IFS1bits.INT2IF=0; //clearing INT2 bit
  PORTBbits.RB3 = 0; //turn off led 
}
```

The problem is that the interrupt is never triggered (I am connecting a cable with 3.3V to the input). I am not sure  the Interrupt is properly set.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Never used that PIC model before, but you should know that in order to set your pin B12 as an input, you need to write 1 to TRISB register, not PORTB register.

Answer (score 1):

From the PIC24FV32KA304 datasheet:

> The pull-downs are enabled separately, using the CNPD1 and CNPD2
>   registers, which contain the control bits for each of the CN pins.
>   Setting any of the control bits enables the weak pull-downs for the
>   corresponding pins.

Therefore, since you never actually enable the weak pull downs, your pin may never come down to a zero state (or at least not in a reasonable time frame) if you have nothing pulling it down externally. The following changes to your code will enable the weak pull downs and hopefully fix your issue:

```
--- //CNPD1bits.CN14PDE = 0;     //pull down resistor
+++ CNPD1bits.CN14PDE = 1;     //pull down resistor
```

Also, as stated by epichorns, the TRISB register is the one that will set the port to input/ouput but the default is to input so it should not be the cause of you issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think you were trying out the wrong PIN.

If you look at the [Family Data Sheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39995d.pdf) page 4, you will notice that PIC24**FV**xxK302 devices have INT2 on PIN 23 (RB12), but PIC24**F**xxK302 on PIN 20 (which is **RA6**).